# sql multiple elements selection

Tags: mysql, select, max

let's say I have the following elements:

**Actions table**

```
id          type        date
----------- ----------  ----------
1           start       2012-01-01 10:00:00
2           suspend     2012-01-01 11:00:00
3           resume      2012-01-01 12:00:00
4           suspend     2012-01-01 13:00:00
5           resume      2012-01-01 14:00:00
6           stop        2012-01-01 15:00:00
7           refill      2012-01-01 16:00:00
8           stop        2012-01-01 17:00:00
```

**Association table**

```
id    actionID    elementID
----- ----------- -----------
1     1           1
2     2           1
3     3           1
4     4           1
5     5           1
6     6           1
7     7           1
8     8           1
```

**Elements table**

```
id    name
----- -----------
1     my element
```

So basically I have an element, its status evolves according to some user triggered actions (action table), thoses actions can be shared through many elements (that's why I have an association table).

What I'd like to retrieve in an SQL query its:

**ElementID, start Action ID, last action ID**(start action is always linked to an element)

is it possible without writing multiple sql queries ? i'm looking for the most performant query since it'll run on a table with many millions of entries (the association table & action table)

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you have a point, in fact I tried many solutions but haven't provided them. In fact the problem is a bit more complicated and I just tried to simplify it. I understand what do you mean and I agree with you, my point was mainly to find some help on how to solve my problem, not seeking a complete answer "sur un plateau d'argent".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select last.elementID, start.actionID as startAction, last.actionID as lastAction
from (
    select elementID, max(actionID) as actionID
    from Association
    group by elementID
    ) last
inner join (
    select elementID, min(actionID) as actionID
    from Association
    group by elementID
    ) start on start.elementID = last.elementID
```

Comment: thanks, that's a preferable way since I can also select all the fields for each table :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.Id, e.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'start' THEN a.actiondate END) AS 'StartAction',
  MAX(CASE WHEN a.type = 'stop' THEN a.actiondate END) AS 'ENDAction'
FROM @actions a 
INNER JOIN @association s ON a.Id = s.actionid
INNER JOIN @elements e ON s.id = e.Id
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
```

Comment: seems nice, but the problem is that I don't know if 'stop' is the last action, any action could be the last one (start, suspend, stop). I need to retrieve the last user action, which could be any

Comment: @kitensei, then you should select the max date. I will update my answer.